# How do you put multiple animations in one render loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How do you put multiple animations in one render loop?

Using Jquery, if you have multiple elements to animate, and want:

1. to give each element it's own discrete value (such as a unique `left` for each)
2. to put all elements inside a *single* master timer, and
3. the movement steps should be based on the *collective*, not any individual in the collection
4. each render loop should update *all* positions without releasing control to the browser between elements for a given step. (but it should release between steps)

How do you do that?

Example:

Let `C` represent a list of divs displayed as columns, positioned with `absolute` positioning and unique left values equal to the sum of the width of all columns to it's left.

`CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC`

Let ^P represent the user's mouse, dragging an element, `P` over the list of columns:

```
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
               ^P
```

The columns, `C` should split apart the width of `^P` at the location of ^P to make room. Like:

```
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC   CCCCCCCCCCC
               ^P
```

The column split should be animated, but the `mousemove` event should not allow the column animations to break, where one column moves to the next step but other have not.

**Problem**

Given an object `oPos` that contains the correct new left values for each column after the animation is complete:

```
oPos[Index] = {
   Left:120,
   Right:300,
   Center:75,
   Width:150,
   $Element:$(ACachedSelector),
}
```

Assigning an animation using the `animate()` method:

```
for(var i in oPos){
   oPos[i].$Element.stop().animate({
      left:oPos[i].Left,         
   },{
      duration: 500,
      queue:false,
   });
}
```

... Does not work correctly, because each of the elements is animated using it's own animation loop and tries to move independently. This has horrible performance and looks awful.

The desired effect is to have all columns to the right of the insert point slide to the right as one unit and as part of one animation. For example, try opening multiple tabs in Firefox and dragging a tab around to reorder the tabs. A gap opens up for you using an animation.

So, how do you put multiple animations in one render loop with Jquery?

Comment: One option may be try to perform (or start) the `insert` effect with `css` `animation` or `transition`, perhaps on `:hover`, which should not affect the ongoing `jquery` animations

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that support combination of animations, it may help you.

https://github.com/emn178/jquery-animations